# reusing cellViews, not purging

Tags: ios, uitableview

I notice that my cellViews don't purge. Meaning, when I scroll up and down, the subviews keep adding up on the cellView that has just been reused... What am I doing wrong?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString* cellIdentifier=@"cell";

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    UIImageView cellView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rectCellFrame];

    NSError* error=nil;
    NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageArray[indexPath.row] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

    UIImage* theImage= [UIImage ImageWithData:imageData];

    [cellView setImage:theImage];

    [cell addSubView:cellView];

    .
    .
    .
    .

    [cell addSubView:moreViews];

}
```

Comment: You can't reuse cells when you create them with autorelease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns a cell (instead of nil), it is a cell that you previously created in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.  Every subview you added to that cell when you first created it is still in it.  If you add more subviews when you get the cell from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`, you'll have extra subviews in the cell.

Your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method should have this basic structure:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *const kIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
            reuseIdentifier:kIdentifier];

        // code here to add subviews to cell.contentView
    }

    // code here to configure those subviews to display the content for indexPath, e.g.
    // set the image of image views and the text of labels.

    return cell;
}
```

The tricky part is accessing the subviews to set their content when the cell was returned by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.  Take a look at [“Programmatically Adding Subviews to a Cell’s Content View” in the *Table View Programming Guide for iOS*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW15), which explains how to use view tags to access the subviews.

Comment: so,can I simply return cell if dequeue returns something? Thus : if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    } else {return cell;} ?

Comment: This is interesting. So, would you say that configuring the subviews would take less time, or memory? I am not sure why not simply recreate the cell.. maybe in another thread?

Comment: Don't worry about that right now.  You need to master the basics first.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to modify the cell's contents dramatically I'd recommend making a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and referencing that instead of the base class.  That way you can make your updates in the subclass's `drawRect` method instead of modifying the `UITableViewCell` in the CFRAIP.

Note that you can also call the cell's `prepareForReuse` method to reset properties before the cell is reused.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding subviews to the cell at each method call. This means, that when a cell is reused, it already has the old subviews. You should remove those before adding the new ones.
E.g. `[cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];`

Answer (score 0):

Each time `- (UITableViewCell*)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is called, `cellView` and `moreViews` are added again to a cell you've already added these `UIView`s to.
Reusable cells don't delete their subviews when you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.
If you want to add subviews, the best solution would be to subclass `UITableViewCell` and add your subviews in the `init` method of the subclassed `UITableViewCell`